# SQL Server stored procedure with/without linkserver to self give different result

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure on my UAT server which I use a link server pointing to production server to retrieve data (so I do not need to transfer the data).

When I deploy it to the production this link server was moved to the production server as well. And on the production, we have set up an exact link server pointing to it self.

The queries were very simple,

```
SELECT 
    Code 
    ,MIN(NAME)  as NAME 
    ,SUM(Qty) AS QTY
    ,E.TYPE1 
FROM
    [IPtoSelf,1433].[DATABASE].[dbo].TABLEA T
    --[DATABASE].[dbo].TABLEA T
INNER JOIN 
    [IPtoSelf,1433].[DATABASE].[dbo].TABLEB E ON T.CODE =  E.CODE
    -- [DATABASE].[dbo].TABLEB E
WHERE 
    YEAR(T.DATE) = 2016
    AND MONTH(T.DATE) = 2
    AND T.SOMEVALUE > 0
GROUP BY 
    T.CODE, E.TYPE1
ORDER BY   
    QTY DESC;
```

I get the result by running the stored procedure:

```
EXEC [dbo].[SP_THE_STORED_PROC]
```

The result from the stored procedure are different with or without the [IPtoSelf,1433] !

I have tried:

1. Run this query outside of stored procedure (i.e. using Management Studio), and the result on queries with link server and without are the same. Every time!
2. Compare to #1, the result from query in stored procedure with linked server is wrong.
3. No matter how many time I run, the wrong value from stored procedure with linked server stays consistent.

4.If I just select the TABLEA OR TABLEB in the stored proc with linkserver, the result is correct (i.e. the same as without link server or run out side of stored procedure).

My problem could be solved by simply do not use a link server to self on my production server. However, I would really like to know what exactly has gone wrong. I have all sorts of guessing from cached network packet to inter-wind query result due to looping, but I cannot prove/debug it.

This is the first time I have seen this and I would really appreciate if anyone have encounter similar issue, or have some idea on where to begin with debugging.

Thanks in advance

Update:2016-04-26

I have not get found a way to do a trace. However, I do minimize my problem scope. This thing is not only happening in the stored procedure, it could also be observed by simply execute a query.

For instance if I run:

```
SELECT 
    T.Code,
    E.Code      
FROM
    [IPtoSelf,1433].[DATABASE].[dbo].TABLEA T
INNER JOIN 
    [IPtoSelf,1433].[DATABASE].[dbo].TABLEB E ON T.CODE =  E.CODE
WHERE 
    YEAR(T.DATE) = 2016
    AND MONTH(T.DATE) = 2
```

The resulted table will have some row that  T.Code <> E.Code.

I think, though, this is something more than filtering order.

Comment: I'm wondering whether filtering is being applied out-of-order because you're using scalar functions in the `WHERE` clause. Does changing the `WHERE` clause to something like `WHERE T.DATE >= '2016-02-01' AND T.DATE < '2016-03-01' ...` change the stored procedure's behaviour? A trace/xevents session on SQL Statement Completed might reveal the difference between using the linked server and not.

Comment: Changing to >= ... <= makes the result correct! I am searching on how to apply "trace/xevents session on SQL Statement Completed" to confirm it. Thanks for reply.